# Overloaded function with two different variable types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want a function that takes a list of a, which are from Eq, and a list of b, which are from Int and gives back a list of a.
I thought it should like this: `multiIndex :: (Eq a, Int b) => [a] -> [b] -> [a]` but I get the following error message:

```
Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘Int’ has kind ‘*’
In the type signature:
 multiIndex :: (Eq a, Int b) => [a] -> [b] -> [a] typecheck
```

The whole function would be:

```
multiIndex :: (Eq a, Int b) => [a] -> [b] -> [a]
multiIndex [] _ = []
multiIndex _ [] = []
multiIndex  toBeExtracted values@(y:ys) = (toBeExtracted !! y) : (multiIndex toBeExtracted ys)
```

How can I fix this so it will accept only a list of Int as the second input?

Comment: If the list of indices is sorted, you can turn this in an *O(m+n)* algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem, as pointed out by the compiler, is that `Int` is a type, not a typeclass. Just rewrite your signature as:

```
multiIndex :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
```

To expand on this slightly:

everything before a `=>` arrow in a type signature should be a "constraint" on any type variables that appear in the main signature. Typically this means restricting types to those that implement one or more typeclasses. The `Eq a` you have in your type signature is a typical example. It says "the `a` that I refer to must be an instance of the `Eq` typeclass".

Since `Int` is not a typeclass, but is actually a type, `Int b` makes no sense here. You're not trying to say "`b` must be an instance of the `Int` typeclass" - you're trying to say that `b` must in fact be the specific type, `Int`.

You actually can to this, with a type equality constraint, which is written like this:

```
(Eq a, b ~ Int)
```

(note that this requires either of a couple of language extensions, which is one good reason among many not to use it unless you need to), and says, as well as "`a` must be an instance of `Eq`", "`b` must be equal to `Int`". And there are more advanced cases where you need to do this. However, most of the time, as in this case, it's totally unnecessary because you can simply replace the type variable `b` by the concrete type you want it to be equal to - here `Int`.